# How can I target layout id from Java inflate

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to Android programming...
I want to programmatically add layouts to a `ScrollView`, so I use this code below

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.img_view, null);
    //set ImageView source
    TextView txtView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.txt_view, null);
    //set TextView text
    myLayout.addView(imgView);
    myLayout.addView(txtView);
    scrllView.addView(myLayout);
}
```

The above code works fine. But I want to know if there is a shorter and easier way to do this, because my code will be bulky, and I will have to create a layout XML file for every view I want to add

Maybe I am thinking instead of creating multiple XML file in my layout folder, I can just have one XML file, having `LinearLayout` as the parent with `ImageView` and `TextView` as children, so `my_layout.xml` will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/img"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I can inflate `my_layout.xml` file in my Java code add target the `ImageView` and `TextView` using their `IDs`

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
ImageView imgView = //find the child of myLayout (ImageView) with ID of img
//set ImageView source
TextView txtView = //find the child of myLayout (TextView) with ID of txt
//set TextView text
```

I want to know if it's possible to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I finally got what I am looking for. The code below worked perfectly

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
ImageView imgView = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.img);
//set ImageView source
TextView txtView = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.txt);
//set TextView text
```